# DB Transaction: can we block just a record, not the whole table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I am trying to insert the data into the `Wallets` table of a SQL Server database.
There are can be many requests at the same time so due to the sensitive info I have to use transactions.

The work flow is the following:

1. read the amount of the user's wallet
2. insert the new record based on the previously received data

I tried different isolation levels but in all the cases the transaction blocks the whole table, not just the record I am working with. Even `ReadUncommitted` or `RepeatableRead` block the whole table.

Is there a way to block only the records I am working with?

---

Let me detail:
I don't use any indexes in the table

The workflow (translating C# into SQL) is the following:

1) Select * from Balance
2) Insert ... INTO Balance

Comment: Did you try the Snapshot levels?

Comment: Do you have UPDATE statement(s) or only INSERT ?

Comment: Post your queries and the involved tables DDL. You can use `with (rowlock)` query hint, but the way you select on the first step is important (the lock might escalate from row to table).

Comment: @j.doe i think you may use audit column with record of Active or inactive so that you can restrict the record in where condition like coulm_Name ='Active'

Comment: Table lock on insert? Sounds like an index/constraint is spending a while checking for duplication.

Answer (score 1):

UPDLOCK is used when you want to lock a row or rows during a select statement for a future update statement

Ttransaction-1 :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test WITH (UPDLOCK) /*read the amount of the user's wallet*/
/* update the record on same transaction that were selected in previous select statement */

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Ttransaction-2 :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

/* insert a new row in table is allowed as we have taken UPDLOCK, that only prevents updating the same record in other transaction */

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I have SELECT outside of any trans & Insert within the  Transaction. And when I use UPDLOCK it does block the table so that another request is fully blocked

Comment: Everything in SQL Server is done inside a Transaction. Whether you explicitly open a transaction by using key words Begin Transaction or not.

**Adding a non-clustered index (with full coverage) over the column(s) in WHERE condition will fix this.**

As documented here(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187373.aspx), UPDLOCK takes update locks and holds them to the end of the transaction.

Without an index to locate the row(s) to be locked, all tested rows are locked, and locks on qualifying rows are held until the transaction completes.

Comment: zacs, how your reply will help me to resolve the blocking issue?

Comment: So when  I use UPDLOCK, it does not allow the second request to be processed until the first one is done. So I had to use NOBLOCK. It's not really what I think I should do. Any other suggestions on how to improve the performance and not block the whole table?

Comment: @J. Doe, You should create a non-clustered index over the column(s) that are used in WHERE clause. It will only lock the rows which satisfies the WHERE condition and allow other transactions to perform insert operation on table.

hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to handle lock escalation process (row - page - table - database). Unfortunately, It makes automatically. But you can get some positive effects if:

1. reduce the amount of data which used in queries
2. optimize queries by hints, indexes etc

For `INSERT INTO TABLE` hint `with (rowlock)` can improve performance.

Also, `select` statement use shared (S/IS) lock types which don't allow any update of data, but doesn't block reading.

Answer (score 1):

you should use optimistic locking. That will only lock the current row. Not whole table.

You can read below links for more reference :-

[optimistic locking](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1501/optimistic-locking-in-sql-server-using-the-rowversion-data-type/)

[Optimistic Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/optimistic-concurrency)